# How to set ACL for K2 items Categories in backend

Tags: k2, acl

Lets say i have 3 k2 categories A, B, C

and defined 2 user groups --> UserGroup1, UserGroup2

The Problem is how can I :
UserGroup1 can only see/edit items in category A and can only select category A as item cate in back-end
UserGroup2 can only see/edit items in category A B and can only select category A B as item cate in back-end

I have ACL Manager component installed

Answer (score 2):

To my knowledge, K2 v2.x does not support permissions for categories. Also, I don't think ACL Manager will be much of help here.
For full ACL implementation of the Joomla core into K2, you should wait for the K2 v3.x. 
However it is still in beta phase, although it supposed it would have been out by now. You should be patient and wait for it.

- **[What's new K2 v3](http://getk2.org/blog/1792-k2-v268-released-whats-coming-in-v270-a-v3-update)**
- **[K2 v3 Beta: for testing purposes](http://getk2.org/blog/2073-first-beta-of-k2-version-3-is-here)**

Comment: thank you for your response.
so the only way is to hack the source code....

how can i do so??

Comment: I didn't say to hack the source code, I consider this to be unrealistic to do it now- better give some time and wait for the new version, or look for other CCKs. And in anyway, how to hack K2 to add permissions for categories is very broad and can not be answered here.

Comment: Very broad indeed. I'm trying to update a project using this awful component, and figuring out how the previous developer managed to restrict access is pretty darn frustrating. ACL, K2 and CB, none of them yield anything obvious. I was a fan of Joomla 7 years ago though.